# How pixel-drawing process performance could be boosted?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin

maybe it's easy question for most of you but is there any alternative for counters for loop in Kotlin. I need it to boost performance. I used nested loops in my template for just checking if this approach makes sense and now I want to speed it up.

My loop looks like below:

```
val rectF = RectF()
for (y in 0 until 256) {
    for (x in 0 until 256) {
       pos = getIndexOfMax(results!![0][y][x])
       if (pos > 0) {
          rectF.left = (x / 256f * w) - xw
          rectF.top = (y / 256f * h) - xh
          rectF.right = (x / 256f * w) + xw
          rectF.bottom = (y / 256f * h) + xh
          canvas.drawRect(rectF, boxPaint)
       }
                    
     }
}
```

As you can see 'x' and 'y' are necessary here to calculate box position. I need to speed-up painting process a little (or more) but I don't know how could I use `.map` in here because I've seen only examples for `foreach` loops where `.map` was used. Sorry but I'm not like a Kotlin veteran I used to work with nested loops because those hadn't affected with significant performance loss.

Comment: That's the fastest way to iterate. You could optimize what you have by avoiding doing the two floating point division operations twice. And you could shift the canvas transform by half a pixel so you don't have to subtract half pixel widths...just add full pixel widths for right and bottom. BUT, I think it would probably be lot faster to work with a Bitmap object and then draw the Bitmap to the canvas.

Comment: Android's Canvas is an abstraction over OpenGL. Each rectangle you draw is four vertices, each with color and position information. Each of the four vertices has to be multiplied by a matrix to position it on the matrix. This is an extremely inefficient way to do pixel art. Bitmap lets you modify individual pixels in an efficient way.

Comment: Many of the Kotlin standard library collection iterating functions like `map()` should be used for anything that is performance critical. They create a brand new list, copying all the contents from one collection to another as they modify it. The functions for `MutableList` that modify list contents in place are OK. And `forEach` is fine because it doesn't create a new list.